# Trouble binding Maven plugin to compile phase

Tags: java, maven, annotations, maven-plugin

I've been trying to write a maven plugin using annotations. My plugin declaration looks like:

```
@Mojo(name = "compile", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.COMPILE, requiresProject = true,     threadSafe = false)
public class CompileMojo extends AbstractMojo
```

And I have this in the pom file which compiles the plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
    <configuration>
    <!-- see http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5346 -->                          <skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>true</skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <id>mojo-descriptor</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>descriptor</goal>
        </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

maven appears to confirm that the plugin is bound to the compile phase:

```
mvn help:describe -DartifactId=jvmbasic-maven-plugin -DgroupId=com.khubla.jvmbasic -Dgoal=compile -Ddetail

[INFO] Mojo: 'jvmbasic:compile'
jvmbasic:compile
    Description: jvmBASIC compiler
    Implementation: com.khubla.jvmbasic.jvmbasicmojo.CompileMojo
    Language: java
    Bound to phase: compile

    Available parameters:

    sourceDir
         where to find the sources
    targetDir
         target dir
    verbose
       verbose
```

When I invoke the mojo explicitly it works:

```
mvn jvmbasic:compile
```

and if I use an executions section in a pom file it also works.  However, I had expected the mojo to be automatically bound to the compile phase, so that if I typed

```
mvn clean compile
```

it would automagically run.  Am I missing something obvious?

The actual source code is here:

https://github.com/teverett/jvmBASIC/tree/master/jvmbasicmojo

Comment: Apart from my answer i see several issues with your maven build (not defined encoding). Examples which use the plugin in the same reactor without correctly defining the dependencies to the plugin. Without manual editing not usable to build out of the box. Generated classes are part of src/main/java (ANTLR generated classes). The problem is that you don't use real multi-module build.

Comment: I took a look at your changes, and checked them out.  There are a lot of great changes in there, thank-you.  However, unless my test of your  code was faulty, the original issue is still there.  The build still does not call jvmbasic:compile automagically.

Answer (score 1):

You seemed having a problem with the [dependency in your pom for your mojo](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/). You should use the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

instead of

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-plugin-tools-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Furthermore it would be cleaner to use the maven-plugin-plugin as follows:

```
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <goalPrefix>jvmbasic</goalPrefix>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-descriptor</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>descriptor</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>help-descriptor</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>helpmojo</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
   </plugin>
```

An other point is to define the maven-compiler-plugin version in the mojo area, cause you don't use a global parent pom for your project.

Comment: ok, I believe I've made the changes you suggest, and the symptoms are the same.  The updated pom is at: https://github.com/teverett/jvmBASIC/blob/master/jvmbasicmojo/pom.xml.  The symptoms haven't changed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the `@Execute` annotation, as describe in the [Maven Plugin Tool for Annotations](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-annotations/index.html):

```
@Mojo(name="compile", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.COMPILE, 
      requiresProject = true, threadSafe = false)
@Execute(goal = "compile", phase = LifecyclePhase.COMPILE)
public class CompileMojo extends AbstractMojo
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is the pom.xml of the project you would automagically like to bind to the compile phase? Your project pom should have something like this in the build section.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <artifactId>jvmbasic-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jvmbasic.version}</version>
        <configuration>
           <sourceDir>${maven.compiler.source}</sourceDir>
           <targetDir>${maven.compiler.target}</targetDir>
        </configuration>

    </plugin>
```

Comment: Have you tried configuring the plugin as above, with sourceDir and targetDir specified? Do you have logging statements in your mojo? What is the value of those params?

Comment: Those params have default values.  Keep in mind that if I call the mojo explicitly with "mvn jvmbasic:compile" it works; it just doesn't work with "mvn compile".